# How to get correct time (Millisecond) with DST timezone in java

Tags: java, timezone, dst

I have a simple for my problem:

```
TimeZone fromTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Santiago");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
System.out.println(calendar.getTime() + " |Mili: " + calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

The output: (My timezone is ICT)

```
Wed Apr 01 19:45:00 ICT 2015 |Milisecond: 1427892300000
```

The problem is: The calendar return wrong time for this Timezone on DST day. The timezone "America/Santiago" should be UTC-3 for now (ref: http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/chile/santiago.) .  It need to show:

```
Wed Apr 01 18:45:00 ICT 2015 |Milisecond: 1427888700000
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not applied the timezone `fromTimeZone` to the calendar .

Comment: Can you tell me how to get actual milisecond for this timezone?

Comment: set time zone `calendar.setTimeZone(fromTimeZone);` before `calendar.getTimeInMillis()`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't add calendar.setTimeZone(fromTimeZone); on my simple. That doesn't work for my problem :(